# Electrical wire a 240v sprinkler lake pump

Tags: electrical

I have a [Wayne 1-1/2 HP Cast Iron Quick-Prime Lawn-Sprinkler Pump](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Wayne-1-1-2-HP-Cast-Iron-Quick-Prime-Lawn-Sprinkler-Pump-WLS150/100017195)

What do I have to do to wire this up? I have a free 30-amp circuit breaker in my panel. This pump has two wires - white and black. Do I just run 2-wire out to the pump and wire up each one?

No ground wire?

**EDIT:**

To clarify what I'm confused about since I wasn't clear enough -

1. There is no ground wire coming off the pump. I see now via the instruction manual that apparently there's a ground screw inside the pump casing - I should connect my ground wire to that, correct?
2. What gauge wire do I need?  It's about a 75 foot run. I will be encasing the wire in metal conduit.
3. Do I then just connect the other two wires from my 3-wire to black and white on the pump, and nothing else required?

Yes, I realize this needs to be grounded.

Yes the breaker in the panel will be a GFCI.

Comment: **Yes ground wire** (or metallic conduit). Perhaps you should call an electrician if you are ready to jump to the conclusion that you don't need one because a green wire was not handed to you.

Comment: I should have clarified - I see no place *on the pump* to connect a ground wire. I assume I need one, the question is where the heck on the pump do I connect it.

Comment: I could say something witty about the obviousness of the use for something labelled Ground Screw, but yeah, make a hook on the end of the bare ground wire that should be in your cable and make sure the hook wraps in the direction the screw tightens. Playing with 240V with a profound lack of knowledge can be the last thing you do before entering the Pearly Gates...

Comment: Read the documentation that came with the pump. There should be either a screw, a terminal,  a clamp, or a hole for a screw on the back of the motor (the end opposite the pump).

Comment: That was part of the my issue - there was NO documentation that came with the pump. :-(  I have since found it online, which is helpful.

Comment: Some pictures might be helpful. Is there a cover on the back of the motor?

Answer (score 3):

Quoting directly from the [installation instructions](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/f6/f627f91a-f285-4e33-8cf0-6a3f889deb5f.pdf)

1. All
   wiring must be performed by a
   qualified electrician. The
   pump must be installed in
   compliance with all local and national codes.
2. Connect this product to a grounded circuit equipped with a ground fault circuit interruptor (GFCI) device.
3. Before installing this product, have the electrical circuit checked by an electrician to ensure proper grounding.

Even has a helpful diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Considering the original question my ONLY advice/answer is to hire an electrician.

One note, the fact that you have a spare 30A breaker in your panel really doesn't mean much. All it means is that you have a spare 30A breaker, and considering that this circuit requires GFCI protection this is not much help.